# using rect argument for drawRect method in custom UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview

How can I possibly use the rect argument passed in drawRect calls, am sure whenever setNeedsDisplayInRect is passed, drawRect method is called for particular region. for now I redraw the text and shapes for entire frame and not constraining to the rect part that needs to be redrawn and I have no idea on how effectively can I use the rect param. 
Any insights on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rect is the region to redraw. In some cases UIKit will redraw only a "dirty" region of your view. You can optimize your code to detect that some of the drawing would occur outside this rect by using `CGRectContainsPoint()` and therefore not do it.

Comment: Thanks, it works, just for clarification, since my draw strings uses rect, i will have to use CGRectContainsRect() instead of CGRectContainsPoint(), isn't it?
 also will that affect performance if used for table cell views

Comment: You can use CGRectContainsRect() for strings. There is a potential speed improvement depending on Apple's implementation of the cell drawing code. You can do simple refresh and scroll tests, and put counters to benchmark if there is a benefit. In my opinion, unless there is some big rendering on your cells, that performance gain would be minimal.